# How to pass selected text in Vim as external program argument?

Tags: vim

I want select some string in visual mode (`v`) and send it to any external program (e.g. `tmux send-keys`)

I tried use xargs:

1. switch to `v` (visual mode)
2. select some words
3. press `:` getting `:'<,'>`
4. Write `:'<,'>w ! xargs -I {} tmux send-keys -t:0 {}`. Getting whole line passed to `tmux`

`xargs` works as expected.

But entire line is always passing instead of my selection.

Answer (score 0):

Shell windows usually do not support selecting text on anything but the client side, meaning only your terminal window or SSH client will know that you have selected text. Therefore, you will likely be hard pressed to find something that can can tell BASH and contained programs what you have selected.